# Unity won't change the scene with either of these scripts i added in my GameManager

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm fairly new to Unity and C#, and can not find a way to change my scene. What might be the issue with both of these as they compile correctly with minimal to no errors. Any sorts of help would be amazing as my due date for this is very soon. Thanks in advance.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class gamemanager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float CurrentBalance;

    public Text CurrentBalanceText;
    public store Store;
    public bool GameFin;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        CurrentBalance = 4000000.00f;

        CurrentBalanceText.text = CurrentBalance.ToString("C2");

        GameFin = false;


    }

    public void gamefinish()
    {
        if (CurrentBalance >= 400000000)
        {
            GameFin = true;
        }
        if (GameFin = true)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneBuildIndex: 1);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void AddToBalance(float amt)

    {
        CurrentBalance += amt;
        CurrentBalanceText.text = CurrentBalance.ToString("C2");

    }

    public bool CanBuy(float amtToSpend)
    {
        if (amtToSpend > CurrentBalance)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }




}
```

or

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class gamemanager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float CurrentBalance;

    public Text CurrentBalanceText;
    public store Store;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        CurrentBalance = 4000000.00f;

        CurrentBalanceText.text = CurrentBalance.ToString("C2");

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void AddToBalance(float amt)

    {
        CurrentBalance += amt;
        CurrentBalanceText.text = CurrentBalance.ToString("C2");

    }

    public bool CanBuy(float amtToSpend)
    {
        if (amtToSpend > CurrentBalance)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    public void GameComp()
    {
        if(CurrentBalance >= 500000000)
            SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneBuildIndex:1);

    }  

}
```

Once again, thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting into the `if` that is actually setting the scene?

Comment: `if (GameFin = true)` should be `if (GameFin == true)` right? Also this is kinda redundant .. why not simply `if (CurrentBalance >= 400000000) { GameFin = true; SceneManager.LoadScene(1); }`? And then .. where/when is `gamefinish` or `GameComp` called?

Comment: Btw since `CurrentBalance` is public anyway your entire method `CanBuy` could simply be written as `amtToSpent <= CurrentBalance`

Answer (score 0):

`gamefinish()` function

is never called on your script? so it never executes.